# Get elapsed time between 2 clicks on the same object in power point slide using VBA

Tags: vba, time, powerpoint

Premise: I never used VBA before..

**What I would like to obtain:**
 directly inside the slide, when I click on a shape or a button, I want to start the timer and when I click again on **the same** object, I want show the elapsed time between the first click and the second one..

Here what I did:

I created a form and I put the following code

```
Private startTime As Date
Private endTime As Date


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
startTime = Now

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    endTime = Now


    TextBox2.Value = startTime
    TextBox3.Value = endTime
    TextBox1.Value = DateDiff("s", startTime, endTime)

End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm using 2 button.. how can I do the same with only 1 button?

Is it possible to do that without using a form?

I think it will be more beautiful directly inside the slide (and actually, it is what I need to do)
If not.. how can I make the form more beautiful? Like change color, style and so on

Could you give me any advice?

Comment: If you use a userform could you make a global variable to note the last time it was clicked and subtract from that instead? Then you’d just not display the diff if the start date is the default for dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to follow if you add VBA code to your presentation first, before adding a special shape that you'll click. The code here goes in a regular module and will be associated directly to the designated shape on whichever slide you choose.

```
Option Explicit

Private alreadyStarted As Boolean

Public Sub ClickCatcher(ByRef actionShape As Shape)
    Debug.Print "shape clicked: " & actionShape.Name
    If Not alreadyStarted Then
        StartCounter
        alreadyStarted = True
    Else
        Dim elapsed As Double
        elapsed = TimeElapsed() / 1000#
        MsgBox "Time Elapsed: " & Format(elapsed, "#.000 sec")
        alreadyStarted = False
    End If
End Sub
```

(I'll show you the timer code below)

It's easy to see that using the global variable `alreadyStarted`, you can toggle the timer to start and stop and report the elapsed time (in milliseconds).

The `Debug.Print` statement shows the name of the shape that was clicked. This **might** be important if you have more than one action shape. So you could perhaps check for the name of the timer shape and not some other one.

The final setup you need is to add an "action shape" to you selected slide. You can do this from the *INSERT* ribbon, then select *Shapes* and scroll all the way to the bottom until you see the Action Shapes. Select any of them you like and add it to a slide. Immediately you'll see a pop-up dialog asking you for the action setting. Make sure you select *Run Macro* and that the name of your routine is selected (`ClickCatcher` in this case).

[image]

Now go into Presentation mode and click once on that shape, then click a second time and the `MsgBox` will pop up showing the elapsed time.

Here's the precision timer code. I'd suggest to create a separate code module and copy this code there.

```
Option Explicit

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' For Precision Counter methods
'
Private Type LargeInteger
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib _
                         "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LargeInteger) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib _
                         "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LargeInteger) As Long

Private counterStart As LargeInteger
Private counterEnd As LargeInteger
Private crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296#               ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

'==============================================================================
' Precision Timer Controls
'
Private Function LI2Double(lgInt As LargeInteger) As Double
    '--- converts LARGE_INTEGER to Double
    Dim low As Double
    low = lgInt.lowpart
    If low < 0 Then
        low = low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = lgInt.highpart * TWO_32 + low
End Function

Public Sub StartCounter()
    '--- Captures the high precision counter value to use as a starting
    '    reference time.
    Dim perfFrequency As LargeInteger
    QueryPerformanceFrequency perfFrequency
    crFrequency = LI2Double(perfFrequency)
    QueryPerformanceCounter counterStart
End Sub

Public Function TimeElapsed() As Double
    '--- Returns the time elapsed since the call to StartCounter in microseconds
    If crFrequency = 0# Then
        Err.Raise Number:=11, _
                  Description:="Must call 'StartCounter' in order to avoid " & _
                                "divide by zero errors."
    End If
    Dim crStart As Double
    Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter counterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(counterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(counterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / crFrequency
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this small mod to what you've got:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Static StartTime As Double
Static Running As Boolean

Running = Not Running

If Running Then
    StartTime = Now
Else
    Running = False
    MsgBox DateDiff("s", StartTime, Now)
End If

End Sub
```